# filtering table by selection : column, condition and value js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter

I want to filter the table in real time by the column, the condition and the value entered by the user, I am zero in js, i am using django and postgres. Table saved at postgres.

*template*

```
<form action="" method="get" class="inline">

        <select name="column" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Choose field</option>
            <option value="title">Title</option>
            <option value="quantity">Quantity</option>
            <option value="distance">Distance</option>
        </select>

        <label for="table">Condition</label>

        <select name="condition" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Choose condition</option>
            <option value="greater">greater</option>
            <option value="contains">contains</option>
            <option value="lower">lower</option>
            <option value="equals">equals</option>
        </select>

        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="search" id="search-text" onkeyup="tableSearch()">

        <button type="submit">Apply</button>
</form>
```

[image]

thanks a lot for  help)

*could it work?*

```
function myFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var tds = tr.getElementsByTagName('td');

    for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        var firstCol = tds[0].textContent.toUpperCase();
        var secondCol = tds[1].textContent.toUpperCase();
        if (firstCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || secondCol.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method?

```
const data = [
  { title: 'spray', quantity: 40, distance: 300 },
  { title: 'pray', quantity: 10, distance: 150 },
  { title: 'grey', quantity: 23, distance: 100 }
];
const result = data.filter(each => each[quantity] < 23 );
console.log(result);
// expected output: Array [{ title: 'pray', quantity: 10, distance: 150 }]
```

you can use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) and dynamically change the condition too.